# Issus with building the java project using maven2

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am using maven2 to build the java project,  when i issue the command `mvn clean install` i am getting the error `could not parse error message:   (use -source 5 or higher to enable generics)`.

In my eclipse environment i am using jdk 1.7 and the project is working fine. when i want to build the project i am unable to do that, think maven is taking java version 1.3 as default.

Any one please help me how to set the jdk versio to 1.7 in maven, to build the project successfully..

Apart from the jars mentioned in pom.xml i want to add add my own jar, how can i specify that in pom xml?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your pom.xml configure  the maven-compiler-plugin  to use 1.6:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: <plugin> 
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
       <configuration> 
         <verbose>true</verbose> 
         <fork>true</fork>          
         <compilerVersion>1.7</compilerVersion> 
       </configuration> 
   </plugin>

Comment: Except that the OP wants to use v1.7 ;-)

Comment: @Bozho, its saying 'unable to download the artifact from repository' do I need to mention the dependency before the plugin?

Comment: Apart from the jars mentioned in pom.xml i want to add add my own jar, how can i specify that in pom xml?

Comment: I didn't get the last question. (fixed the 1.6->1.7)

Comment: i have one jar file which is created by me, i want to use that jar in the  build. how can i do that?